# If sigma (a certain series) converges, is the reversed series also converges or diverges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If sigma (a certain series) converges (series with positive terms)
does the revered version of that certain series also converges? or it diverges? can we conclude anything ?

Comment: What do you mean by "reversed"?

Comment: For convergent series $\,\sum a_n = a \implies \sum \lambda a_n = \lambda a\,$, if you are asking about the case $\,\lambda = -1\,$.

Comment: If the series is not conditionally convergent, any permutation of the terms will still result in a convergent sum.

Comment: i mean reversed >> reciprocal